# Pin Pad. A custom control like this one

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I recently tried out a Free-To-Play MMORPG game called [AIKA](http://aika.t3fun.com/Home/Home.aspx)

While trying the game out, I found a very nice PIN Pad that allows for you to protect your characters. I have a screen shot attached:

[image: Security Pin Pad]

It allows for a user to enter (through mouse-only) a four digit numeric code. A cool thing is that the numeric digits around the InputBox are always shuffled every time this screen comes on.

My purpose behind this question is: Is there someone out there who has created something like this before? I'm interested in using this in my WinForms and WPF application.

Note I have done a lot of searching but I guess I really don't know if I'm using the correct keywords. In case, such a control doesn't exist, and someone is willing to make one, kindly drop a line here. I'm very interested.

Comment: Erm, what is the advantage of the numbers moving around each time? To make it even *harder* to use?

Comment: yup... you don't know these UK BCH clients...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it pops up on the screen, it's really just a form with buttons on it.  You can create a simple randomization routine to populate the button numbers.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int[] array = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
  Random rnd = new Random();
  for (int i = array.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
  {
    int j = rnd.Next(i);
    int k = array[j];
    array[j] = array[i - 1];
    array[i - 1] = k;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
  {
    panel1.Controls["Button" + (i + 1).ToString()].Text = array[i].ToString();
  }
```

[image]

Comment: @Hassan All I did was dock a panel to the top to hold the 10 buttons  to separate them from the rest of the form.

Comment: The space in the center is actually a TextBox or a NumericBox